# Buttons do different thing for portrait and landscape orientations

Tags: android

In portrait mode,I have an application with three buttons. When the user hits the first button  text #1 will appear and if the user hits the second button the text #1 disappears and text #2 appears in the same place, same idea with button three. I'm trying to let the text view appears with an image for each button in only landscape orientation mode. Please can I do that? see my codes below. Thanks!

XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recipe 1"
    android:id="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/response"
    android:layout_below="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button15" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recipe 2"
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recipe 3"
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="android.webkit.WebViewFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Java:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.android.R.*;


public class Recipes extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView resp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_recipes);
    resp = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.response);
    Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(id.click_btn);
    Button c = (Button)this.findViewById(id.button15);
    Button d = (Button)this.findViewById(id.button16);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c.setOnClickListener(this);
    d.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipes, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.click_btn: /** on click_btn button click */
            resp.setText("2   medium sweet potatoes (about 1 pound total) \n1/2  teaspoon salt\n1/2  teaspoon ground cumin\n1/2  teaspoon chili powder\n1/2  teaspoon paprika\n1/4  teaspoon ground black pepper");
            break;

        case R.id.button15: /** on button15 button click */
            resp.setText("1 large egg yolk, at room temperature\n1/2 cup extra-virgin olive oil; more for grilling\n2 teaspoons minced fresh flat-leaf parsley\n1 teaspoon minced fresh tarragon\n1 1/2 teaspoons fresh lemon juice; more to taste Kosher salt");
            break;

        case R.id.button16: /** on button16 button click */
            resp.setText("1/2 cup butter, softened\n1 cup packed light brown sugar\n1 1/2 cups all-purpose flour\n3 cups rolled oats\n1 teaspoon ground cinnamon");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use different layout for landscape with ImageView.

You can create landscape layout in layout-land folder in res. If there is no layout-land folder then create one.

Create new landscape layout in layout-land folder with the same name as in default layout.

You have to check for null pointer in java code because there is no image view in default mode.

Comment: @Crazecoder I already created the same xml file in layout-land folder but the image i want to be appeared when the same button when is clicked on landscape mode only, not on portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
```

checks if you are in Landscape Mode in Java but if I understand your question right, you probably want to set your whole activity to fixed landscape. Do this in your manifest :

```
<activity
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```